# In PlayN, how do I use the Storage interface to persist data?

Tags: playn

I'm looking for a code example that demonstrates practical real-world usage of the [`Storage` interface](http://docs.playn.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html). I'm especially interested in HTML5 implementation. I've just started working on my own proof-of-concept, so I'll post that if no better answers arrive before then.

The Storage interface is introduced in this Google presentation here:

- [http://playn-2011.appspot.com/](http://playn-2011.appspot.com/slides/index.html#40)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that demonstrates the use of the storage interface together with PlayN's JSON interface:

```
private void loadStoredData() {
    // storage parameters
    String storageKey = "jsonData";
    Json.Object jsonData = PlayN.json().createObject();  

    // to reset storage, uncomment this line
    //PlayN.storage().removeItem(storageKey);

    // attempt to load stored data
    String jsonString = PlayN.storage().getItem(storageKey);

    // if not loaded, create stored data
    if ( jsonString == null ) {
        DemoApi.log("stored data not found");
        jsonData.put("firstWrite", new Date().toString());

    // else display data
    } else {
        jsonData = PlayN.json().parse(jsonString);
        DemoApi.log("stored data loaded");
        DemoApi.log("data first written at " + jsonData.getString("firstWrite"));
        DemoApi.log("data last read at " + jsonData.getString("lastRead"));
        DemoApi.log("data last written at " + jsonData.getString("lastWrite"));
    }

    // update last read
    jsonData.put("lastRead", new Date().toString());

    // write data (this works in Java -- not in HTML)
    // see https://stackoverflow.com/q/10425877/1093087
    /*
    Json.Writer jsonWriter = PlayN.json().newWriter();
    jsonWriter.object(jsonData).done();
    jsonString = jsonWriter.write();
    */

    // alternative write routine
    Json.Writer jsonWriter = PlayN.json().newWriter();
    jsonWriter.object();
    for ( String key : jsonData.keys() ) {
        jsonWriter.value(key, jsonData.getString(key));
    }
    jsonWriter.end();
    jsonString = jsonWriter.write();

    // store data as json
    PlayN.storage().setItem(storageKey, jsonString);

    // confirm
    if ( PlayN.storage().isPersisted() ) {
        DemoApi.log("data successfully persisted");
    } else {
        DemoApi.log("failed to persist data");
    }
}
```

There's one little hitch with the `Json.Writer` that seems a bit buggy that I document in this question here: [In the HTML version of PlayN, why does the following JSON-handling code throw an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425877)